# Simple regex C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have:

```
<span id="WidgetMain1_WidgetContact1_City_lbl">Woodside, </span>
<span id="WidgetMain1_WidgetContact1_State_lbl">NY</span>
```

I want to get name Woodside and State NY, I try:

```
 Regex rl = new Regex(@"WidgetMain1_WidgetContact1_City_lbl/"">(.+?)</span>");
 Regex nn = new Regex(@"WidgetMain1_WidgetContact1_State_lbl/"">(.+?)</span>");
```

It does not work in both cases :(

Comment: Why do you have an extra forward slash in your patterns (i.e. `lbl/`)?

Answer (score 0):

As Kenneth posted, you have an error near the double quotes, if you remove the forward slash it will work.

Also, a recommendation, if you can, avoid the dot, in your case I would change (.+?) to ([^<>]*?), in this way it will take only what is between the span (if there is no html tag), the dot is slow and can cause a lot of troubles on long documents.

Cheers.